# The equation $A x=b$ has a solution $x \in \mathbb{R}^{k}$ whenever $y \in Null(A^T)~ \Rightarrow y \in~ Null(b^T)$

Tags: linear-algebra

If $b^{T} y=0$ for every $y \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$ such that $A^{T} y=0$, show that the equation $A x=b$ has a solution $x \in \mathbb{R}^{k}$.

Here if $b \neq 0$, how can we say that  $rank(A:b)=rank(A)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Consider the relationship between the rank of $[A \mid b]$ and the nullspace of
$$
[A \ \mid \ b]^T = \pmatrix{A^T\\ b^T}.
$$